# Draw circle line and then erase it

Tags: javascript, animation, math, canvas

I have a simple script where by I am trying to draw a circle when a mouse goes over the canvas and it takes about 2000 milliseconds, when the mouse leaves the canvas it then erases the circle.

I got most of it working - it draws the circle correctly, but the mouse out does not fully work as it keeps restarting.

This is my code:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseover',fill,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout',erase, false);
function fill(){
    circle.animate    = true;
    circle.direction  = 1;
}
function erase(){
    circle.animate    = true;
    circle.direction  = 0;  
}


function maths(){
    if(circle.animate == true){
        var amount  = circle.vector * deltaTime;
        if(circle.direction == 1){
            circle.curAngle += amount;
        }else if(circle.direction == 0){
            circle.curAngle -= amount;   
        }

        if(circle.curAngle % 2 == 0){
            circle.curAngle = 0;
        }
        if(circle.curAngle == circle.endAngle){
            circle.animate = false;   
        }

   }
}

function draw(){
    deltaTime = Date.now() - frame;
    frame     = Date.now();
    maths();

    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 100, circle.startAngle * Math.PI, circle.curAngle * Math.PI,false);
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    context.stroke();

    setTimeout(draw,1);

}

frames = Date.now();
draw();
```

I have made a fiddle of it too: **http://jsfiddle.net/hru7xyfu/**, to reproduce the error mouse over the canvas and wait for it to fully fill up then mouse out and you see the circle keeps restarting after it has fully erased it.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: The `circle.animate = false;` never gets executed, this usually occurs because your circle is never a perfect circle but gets erased right as it becomes full. One solution is to add some form of tracking variable to see if the circle passes a threshold size while going in a direction, then stopping all animations. Am tinkering with the code now

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin i also noticed my `% 2 == 0` doesn't seem to actually work either =/

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `%2 ==0` given that your circle size is 1.5 at most?

Comment: Because `east` in javascript is considered `0 * Math.PI` i believe? So i was just setting the angle to 0 instead of it climbing infinitly.

Comment: Late to the game, but.  Your problem boils down to doing floating point number comparisons.  You end up comparing `1.5 == 1.499999999` or `1.5 == 1.500000001` and never quite hit it, so you never stop animating.  This was easiest to debug when I added in a label to display the current angle.  http://jsfiddle.net/hru7xyfu/6/

Comment: Cleaned up to require less logic:  http://jsfiddle.net/hru7xyfu/8/

Comment: @gilly3 good stuff dude thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if(circle.curAngle == circle.endAngle){
    circle.animate = false;   
}
```

with:

```
if(circle.curAngle < circle.endAngle){
    circle.curAngle = circle.endAngle
    circle.animate = false;   
}
if(circle.curAngle > circle.endAngle + 2){
    circle.curAngle = circle.endAngle + 2
    circle.animate = false;   
}
```

The second if statement solves an issue where the circle grows too large (though you can't see it, because it starts overlapping itself)

Updated JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hru7xyfu/2/

Comment: Do i still need line 36 in the jsfiddle which resets the angle to 0 ? I currently can't seem to get that to reset the angle?

Comment: No, I think you can take that if statement (if(circle.curAngle % 2 == 0)) and body out.

Comment: @JosiahK i just noticed the animation does not seem to go the length of time that i set (2000 milliseconds) - not sure why this is.